# MySQL SELECT the 5 most recent IDs

Tags: mysql, limit, max

I simply want to spit out the 5 most recent rows created (IDs) so I may compare to another database for an insert and update on duplicate via php:

```
SELECT MAX(ID), MAX(DATE) from table ORDER BY ID LIMIT 5
```

Should spit out something like this:

```
ID      DATE
4018    2012-03-01
4017    2012-03-01
4016    2012-02-25
4015    2012-02-15
4014    2012-02-11
```

Comment: It does work I had been confused on when to use DESC because one of my Fields I named DESC!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `DESC` sort to get the highest values first.  I'm assuming that your IDs are created incrementally...

```
SELECT ID, DATE from table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 3):

If for some reasons the higher IDs don't come with a more recent date, you can use this to get a "real" sort by date:

```
    SELECT id, date FROM table ORDER BY date_format(date, '%Y%m%d') DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Links:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: This may prove beneficial while doing further testing thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `MAX` unless you want a single row, or when using `GROUP BY`. Your query should be simply

```
SELECT ID, DATE from table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the current query. According to your description, you just want order your result by id desc. Why do you use MAX(ID) and MAX(DATE). I just remember you that DATE is a reserved keyword.

I think the query should be `SELECT ID,`DATE`FROM table ORDER BY ID DEST LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0`